# Haxe - Adding an event to process exit?

Tags: process, exists, haxe, event-listener

Haxe porgramming beginner here and I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

I'm simply running another program on the computer via sys.io.Process.

```
import sys.io.Process;
import neko.Lib;

class Main 
{
    static function main() 
    {

        var cProcess = new Process(pClient + sArgs);
    }

}
```

I only want my Haxe program to be running as long as the "cProcess" exists.
So I need some kind of Eventhandler that calls a function when the cProcess is being closed.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?
Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is wait for the process to complete it's execution 
just call `exitCode()`, it will block until launched process exits.

```
var cProcess = new Process(pClient + sArgs);
cProcess.exitCode();
trace("Done!");
```

Answer (score 1):

Mihail's solution is simple and should work.

If you need more on that, you can try [asys](https://github.com/benmerckx/asys), which is the asynchronous version of the sys package in Haxe standard library.

```
var process = new asys.io.Process('your command');
process.exitCode().handle(function(code) trace('process exited with code: $code'));
```

It also depends on the platform you are running on. If you are running on platforms with async io like nodejs, things should be simple. Otherwise you have to consider threads.